# Cron job time syntax

Tags: cron, cpanel, cron-task

I have a cron job that processes an action for several records in my database. I want it to process each record with a 5 minute delay, then repeat the process every 12 hours. What is the syntax that I need to use to make this happen? For example, if I have 5 rows in my database that the cron job will process. I want it to process the first row, then process the next row 5 minutes later, then process the next row 5 minutes later, etc. until all rows have been processed. Then repeat the whole process every 12 hours. I tried using `*/5 */12 * * *` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work the way you have configured.

> if I have 5 rows in my database that the cron job will process. I want it to process the first row, then process the next row 5 minutes later, then process the next row 5 minutes later, etc

Write a shell scrip to achieve above goal. Cron won't do it for you. **Hint:** use `sleep` function in your scrip to wait for 5 minutes before processing next record.

> Then repeat the whole process every 12 hours

use `* */12 * * *` in cron to let your shell script run after every 12 hrs.

So, in short, Cron will trigger a `run` of you script very 12 hrs AND your script has the logic to wait for 5 minutes between processing any two consecutive DB records.

Comment: Thanks slayedbylucifer

Comment: @Angelo Rodriguez, If you find this answer helpful, then you should [Upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130047/244809) is and if this answer resolves your question, then you should [Accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it. That's the way `Thank you` works on stackoverflow.

Comment: Only users with a reputation score of 15+ can upvote. Or else I would. Thanks.

Comment: @AngeloRodriguez You can always accept answers to your questions, regardless of your rep score.